# Incorrect background image being shown by XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I created an XML with a relativelayout that has a webview and a relativelayout inside it. What I did is that I load my app on the webview and the app logo below it using the relativeLayout1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/urlContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/footerl" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But what happens is that the image is correct on portrait on small devices, but becomes distorted on larger devices or when on landscape mode(Once I rotate it). So what I did was I added different sizes of the image on the /res folder:

```
res/drawable-hdpi/footer.png
res/drawable-ldpi/footer.png
res/drawable-xdpi/footer.png
res/drawable-xxdpi/footer.png
```

each of the image has a different size, using the maximum width of every device(320px, 480px, 780px, 1200px)

I also used different layouts:

```
 layout/activity_web.xml
 layout-large/activity_web.xml
 layout-xlarge/activity_web.xml
 layout-xlarge-land/activity_web.xml
```

Still the logo below is distorted. All of the layouts are in portrait mode except the *layout-xlarge-land* which is in landscape mode. Should I create landscape modes for layout & layout-large ?

**UPDATE**

I tried Darnmason's answer by adding an image view to see if it will work even though it is rotated into landscape mode:

but what happens is that the image showing but it's width is similar to portrait mode. Did I miss anything as to why it is not stretching?

Comment: The id relativeLayout1 is not defined in that xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an image as a background doesn't give you much control over image scaling. I would recommend using an `ImageView` setting

```
android:src="@drawable/footer"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

and maybe you'll need `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

This will ensure the image fills the screen, cropping as necessary depending on the aspect ratio of the device. It would still make sense to have a portrait and landscape version but you won't have to care about the slight variances in aspect ratio between devices. Some are more wide-screen than others!

Comment: I tried this solution but what happens is that when I rotate it to landscape, what happens is that the footer image is not stretched, but it is in the same with as it was in portrait mode, I'll update my question with what I did.

Comment: I got it working now. I just forgot to change the width to "fill_parent". Thanks!!