# Displaying a png image in the background of my fragment in Android Application

Tags: android, android-fragments

After having read the posts in Stackoverflow relating to this topic, I implemented the suggestions, however, I am unable to display the image as my background in my application.  Although Studio displays the image in the Design tab, however, when actually running the application, my background image fails to appear and i really do not know why.  I have also added different sizes of the images in the different drawable folder (hdpi, mdpi etc..).

Here is layout for my fragment that incorporates the image:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" >
```

Comment: Please check the log for outOfMemoryError It happens if the bitmap is large.

Comment: thanks or the reply. I have a  "Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4129x4629, max=4096x4096)" message in the Log.  What would you suggest I do?  How do i reduce the memory size?

Comment: You should reduce the size manually, then use sample size . Which is available in android official site http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: so the numbers i quoted above from the log are in pixels or dp?

Answer (score 0):

Using a PNG image as the background of a view is not ideal as you have no control over the scaling of it, it'll stretch to fit the size of the view.

I've outlined a better solution in this question: [Incorrect background image being shown by XML Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102324/incorrect-background-image-being-shown-by-xml-layout/28102399#28102399)

The solution is to add an ImageView with a src and scale type to handle different aspect ratios:

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: Good solution. But the scenario is, no image is displayed rather than streched images.

Comment: Well I've solved your next problem after you deal with the image size issue. Check out this guide to screen sizes so you can arrange your mdpi, hdpi etc images. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html